# Triggering shell_exec method in php

Tags: php, pdf, adobe, shell-exec

The command inside shell_exec method will obviously work on command line. I tried this method on web server but it doesn't work. Is there any additional syntax on how to trigger this?

```
echo shell_exec("'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader>AcroRd32.exe' /t C:\Documents and Settings\cgcuser\My Documents\Downloads\Documents\sample.pdf \\myserver\myprinter");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to escape your backslashes.

Also, your second argument looks like it needs to be enclosed as a String.

```
echo shell_exec("'C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader>AcroRd32.exe' /t 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\cgcuser\\My Documents\\Downloads\\Documents\\sample.pdf' \\\\myserver\\myprinter");
```

Comment: Well, in my opinion, this looks wrong: "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader>AcroRd32.exe". Perhaps you mean to use "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe". You should apply some basic debugging yourself. You definitely need to escape backslashes (use \\ in place of \) but any other problem is something that you need to figure out yourself, really. Your program could be failing to run for any number of reasons.

Comment: when i use this part of cmd line "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" it doesn't work also even if i replace this part into \\ in AcroRd32.exe . But when i put this part "'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader>AcroRd32.exe'" it appears a file on my local drive AcroRd32.exe' the single quote on that file will possibly result on the last single quote on the command line which has escape by the \\ .

Answer (score 0):

use \\ instead of \ , because you used " instead of ';

Comment: where can i put this \\ ? in replacing all \ to \\ ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a different approach wich works fine in Windows 10

```
$WshShell   = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec      = $WshShell->Run("AcroRd32.exe /t my.pdf", 0, true);
```